# Abnormal behavior occurs when docker run directly starts the program

Tags: docker, runtime-error, database-connection

I want to run my program when create a docker container, start command is `/app/<program>`, this program will call and connect another ODBCServer process by thrift rpc to use mysql database connection.

When i use

```
docker run -it --rm --name test <program>:0.1.0
```

and exec

```
# /app/<program>
```

in bash by manually after entering container, everything is normal.

But when i try to run

```
docker run -it --rm --name test <program>:0.1.0 bash -c "/app/<program>"
```

log shows

```
Transport Error, OS(32) Broken Pipe, RPC Server Crashed
```

- Use `docker run -d ... && docker exec -it bash -c "/app/<program>"`
- Use `CMD/ENTRYPOINT "/app/<program>"` in Dockerfile

All attempts show that as long as enter the docker container bash and execute this command, there will be no problem.

Comment: Do you have `CMD/ENTRYPOINT "/app/<program>"` in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I try to use `CMD ["bash", "-c", "/app/<program>"]`, `CMD ["/app/<program>"]` and `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "/app/<program>"]`.

Comment: You have all three in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: No, I tried all three separately, not simultaneously

Comment: What is the `<program>` you need to run? Eg Python, Java etc